# replace character in file during load in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like replace comma by a dot in all columns on my csv file during the `copy into` in snowflake ? Is it possible ? if no, how can do this ?

thanks in advance fo you help

Comment: HI if you are loading from CSV file with a COPY command you can do data conversion within the copy command by putting a SELECT in your copy command as a subquery., you can use the REPLACE to replace comma by a dot.

Comment: i try this ```copy into PUBLIC.STOCK from (select 'HKK9NB','HKTUN2','HKTVN2','HKN6N2','HJL7NB','HJDBN1','HKE0DX','HKTYN2','HKTZN2',try_to_decimal('HKD8VA'),
try_to_decimal('HKD7VA') from @test_database/ST12290501.csv) file_format=FORMATCSV;```
 but the error's message is that 'Numeric value 'HKK9NB' is not recognized'

Comment: Please update your question with the table definition for PUBLIC.STOCK. But basically it appears you are trying to write the value 'HKK9NB' to a numeric field - which obviously won't work.

Comment: 'HKK9NB' and other are the name of my columns in my csv file.

Comment: table definition from stock : 'col1', 'col2 etc

Comment: Columns names don't work in a COPY INTO SELECT statement.  You are selecting from a file, not a table.  Try using positional notation, instead.  This would be replacing column names with $1, $2, etc.

Comment: yes it works, thanks !